# Regex search for pattern within single line

Tags: regex

I have the following text. It's in the single line and I want to search it for file names (file1.pdf, file2.pdf etc.).

```
<i class="attachment-ref">(See attached file: file1.pdf)</i><i class="attachment-ref">(See attached file: file2.pdf)</i>some text<i class="attachment-ref">(See attached file: file3.pdf)</i>some other text
```

Regex:

```
\<i class=\"attachment-ref\"\>\(.*\:\s(.+?)\)\<\/i\>
```

This regex works good when  tags are split into separate lines. 
**What should I change to make it work in the single line?** 
This example is available here: https://regex101.com/r/6dJWuC/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `.*` non-greedy by adding a `?` after it

```
\<i class=\"attachment-ref\"\>\(.*?\:\s(.+?)\)\<\/i\>
```

https://regex101.com/r/PxEtrL/1

Answer (score 1):

The first capturing group of this regular expression will give you the file name : `file:\s(\w+\.\w+)`

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/C9FBWD/2)